# If I put an object into a NSDictionary will there be a strong pointer to it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

If I put an object into a NSDictionary will there be a strong pointer to it? I just want to make sure that it won't get deleted (using ARC) while I still need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they wont get deleted. Dictionaries and arrays retain your objects and release them as soon as they are themselves released or the objects are removed from them.

Comment: But so long as I have a strong pointer to the dictionary, the objects in it will be kept?

Comment: Isn't this saying two different things?  You say "No, there won't be a strong pointer" but then you say "it will be retained".  Maybe it was because of the word "pointer" but sounds like a strong reference to me.

Comment: AH!  That makes so much sense now ><

Comment: Do you happen to know also if a `UIView` type object gets released if it automatically removes itself from its superview, or does that need to still be done manually

Comment: It happens automatically: You have viewA and viewB. You add viewB in viewA, then viewA retains viewB - and it has a responsibility for the memory management. When viewB is removed from viewA, viewA releases it automatically. - this is also valid if not using ARC, so you should never worry that an object added to dictionary or array, or view to another view will be lost...

Comment: But w/o ARC, you have to release the subview after adding it to the superview.